# Unable to connect to remote sql servers using pypyodbc (Python)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I tried to use pypyodbc module to access remote MS SQL database 2014. However, when I run the below script, I got the error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\myscirpt.py", line 159, i
n <module>
    db= pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+ driver + ';SERVER='+ client_db_ip +';PO
RT=' + port + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';trusted_connection=yes;')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2454, in __init__
    self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, read
only)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2507, in connect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1009, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 987, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Clien
t 11.0]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote ho
st.\r\n')
```

Below it's a very simple code for the db connection. The point here is that I can manually connect to the client db from the same machine, which is the one that my python script resides at. I'm curious what actually cause such issue?

```
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
client_db_ip = 'client_db_ip'  # client server ip
port = '1433'
database = 'UPG_TEST_MAIN'
db= pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+ driver + ';SERVER='+ client_db_ip +';PORT=' + port + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';trusted_connection=yes;')
print db
db.close()
```

Comment: It may be a typo, but client_prod_db_ip does not equal client_db_ip.

Comment: @RudyTheHunter Sorry for the misleading, I just updated the post, I can confirm it's not typo

Comment: Try printing your connection string prior to the connect statement to confirm that it looks right.  If you meant to type client_prod_db_ip and  equal client_db_ip in your example code, you are not getting the values that you expect in the connection string.

Comment: *I can manually connect to the client db from the same machine*...how? Mgmt Studio?

Comment: @Parfait Correct, I can use SSMS to connect the db without any issues.

Comment: Look [online](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+ho&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=SQL+Server+An+existing+connection+was+forcibly+closed+by+the+remote+host) for solutions to the error with many suggestions (odbc drivers, # of connections, etc.). You may need to discuss with your DBA or post on [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).